# Microsoft Graph API beta/reports has no data

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to access MFA information for my account using the Microsoft Graph API. This information is included in the beta version of the API and is located at `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails`. Although I can GET this with no issue, there seem to be no results available, as the response is:

```
{'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails', 'value': []}
```

when I expect something more like:

```
"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.credentialUserRegistrationDetails)",
  "value":[
    {
      "id" : "id-value",
      "userPrincipalName":"userPrincipalName",
      "userDisplayName": "userDisplayName-value",
      "authMethods": ["email", "mobileSMS"],
      "isRegistered" : false,
      "isEnabled" : true,
      "isCapable" : false,
      "isMfaRegistered" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

I make this API call using the `reports.read.all` permission and whilst I may be lacking other permissions to be able to access the data, I really have no idea how to start troubleshooting this issue. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on why I cant see any `"value"` data?

Comment: To narrow down this issue, please make sure that there is data for `/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails` in your tenant. You can quickly test it in Microsoft Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer.

Comment: Can you see the reports from Azure portal?

Comment: I checked using the link you supplied and I an empty`"value"` array in this case too. If you are referring to the Multi-Factor Authentication Menu activity reports there seem to be no results here, although I have users set up on MFA.

Comment: Please follow this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-methods-usage-insights#how-it-works to see if you can see the reports about SSPR and MFA on Azure Portal.

Comment: Following the link you have sent, I can see from the page Usage and Insights page that I do have access to the information on who has MFA and SSPR registered.

Comment: If so, you should be able to see the reports through MS Graph. Try to contact  MS support for further investigation.